# Ballerina project won't import package and gives compile error

Tags: ballerina

The [Ballerina](http://ballerina.io) project I'm working on is structured as below.

```
.
Ballerina.toml
LICENSE
README.md
ballerina-internal.log
ballerina.conf
contributions_from_outsiders_log
org
  └── wso2
       └── contributions_from_outsiders
           ├── ballerina-internal.log
           ├── const.bal
           ├── database_client.bal
           ├── gmail_client.bal
           └── structs.bal
 weekly_mail_notifier.bal
```

The contents of my Ballerina.toml file is:

```
[project]
org-name = "pasanwijesinghe"
version = "0.0.1"
```

I'm trying to use a function in `contributions_from_outsiders` from `weekly_mail_notifier.bal`

```
import org.wso2.contributions_from_outsiders;

function main (string[] args) {
    contributions_from_outsiders:generateMailBody();
}
```

Building gives the following error

```
Compiling source
weekly_mail_notifier.bal
invalid organization name recieved: '$anon'. organization name should be lowercase and alphanumeric, underscore is can be used. should be less than 256 characters.
error: ./weekly_mail_notifier.bal:17:1: cannot resolve package 'org.wso2.contributions_from_outsiders'
pasanwijesinghe/org:0.0.1
error: ./weekly_mail_notifier.bal:24:5: undefined package 'contributions_from_outsiders'
error: ./weekly_mail_notifier.bal:24:5: undefined function 'generateMailBody'
ballerina: compilation contains errors
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have given as the package import statement in `weekly_mail_notifier.bal` is wrong here. The import package statement should have the format of `<organization-name>/<package-name>`. According to your project structure, the organization name is "pasanwijesinghe", which is derived from the Ballerina.toml file, and the package name would be "org" here. The "org" is derived for the first directory where the project source resides. In a ballerina project, all the top level directories will be considered as a package. So the correct import statement would be:

```
import pasanwijesinghe/org;

function main (string[] args) {
    org:generateMailBody();
    // rest of the program
}
```

In here, I'm assuming that there is a function `generateMailBody` in your project that is defined in any ballerina source file under any directory. More information about ballerina packages and structure can be found from here : https://ballerina.io/learn/how-to-structure-ballerina-code/#packages